# soap inspecting the xml in Delphi

Tags: xml, web-services, delphi, soap, wsdl

I am trying to understand how to configure a SOAP set of functions for ebXML in DELPHI, but I am stuck at first base.

I have followed Craig Chapman's tutorial (at http://web.archive.org/web/20150822142243/http://chapmanworld.com/2015/03/30/creating-and-consuming-soap-services-in-delphi/) and got it to run OK.

However, I want to see the xml that it is passing when it is running "live", so I can see how close it is to the XML that I am trying to deliver, via SOAP, and to work out how it links to the WSDL that Craig's tutorial has produced.

I can see the WSDL info, but I cannot see the information that the program has passed.

Comment: I have found an old answer (2008) on Delphi Groups: - I have put in the question.

Comment: Please do not put answers in your question. You can answer your own question. You can even mark it as the correct answer after two days.

Comment: I rolled back your edit, because it is inappropriate. If you want to self-answer, do so by writing an actual answer in the space provided to do so, just like an answer to any other question. For more information, see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Create the event and add this code into the WebModule

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModuleBeforeDispatch(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  sl: TStringList;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sl.Add(Request.URL);
    sl.Add(Request.InternalScriptName);
    sl.Add(Request.Method);
    sl.Add(Request.ContentFields.Text);
    sl.SaveToFile('c:\temp\temp.txt');
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't monitor Stack Overflow too closely. On my blog I could have answered sooner...

I'd suggest you try running fiddler: https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler4 - It intercepts HTTP traffic and will give you the raw packet information sent back and forth. I find it invaluable for debugging JSON services.

- Craig Chapman